# Look for strict file in strict folder directory (optimization) at Powershell

Tags: powershell

Could you suggest better optimizzation option how to strict filesearch in specific folder

exmp. there are smb share \10.10.10.10\%randomname%\2018\filename.xlsx

I'm not that good at poweshell but i've been using this option, it perfectly finds **filename.xlsx** in any share location.

```
  $Files = Dir '\\10.10.10.10\' -Recurse | ? {$_.Name -eq "filename.xlsx"} | Select -ExpandProperty FullName
        $excl=New-Object -ComObject "Excel.Application"
        foreach ($file in $Files)
....
```

But with folder structure grow we need it to find only in most relevant folders \2018\filename.xlsx for example, and avoid recheking 2017, 2016 and wasting time.

any thoughts on how to do smth like > `{$_.Name -eq "2018\filename.xlsx"}` :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $Files = Dir '\\10.10.10.10\*\2018\' -Recurse | ? {$_.Name -eq "filename.xlsx"} | Select -ExpandProperty FullName
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$Files = (Get-ChildItem -Path "\\10.10.10.10\*\2018" -Include 'filename.xlsx' -File -Recurse ).FullName
```

Comment: This some how didn't worked for me, but you used asterisk *... i didn't think about this option. So i just used it in my code and it worked well. Thanks for a Tip!

Comment: Oh, then probably you are using a Powershell version earlier then 3.0 ?

Comment: It' was upper version 5.0